# symfony composer update twbs where are the files?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, assetic

I've added

```
"twbs/bootstrap" : "3.3.5",
"components/jquery" : "2.1.4"
```

to my composer.json file.

I've run composer:update with no problems.

However now it's time to use assetic to create the files and composer used symlinks to install the components and twbs folders.

In the ::base.html.twig I would write something like the following...

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets filter = 'cssrewrite'
                 '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.css'
                 '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootsrtap-theme.css'
                 '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/custom.css'
            %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
 {% endstylesheets %}
```

however the path for the rewrite is not correct because of the symlink installed by composer...

My question: Where did the files actually go?
Or is there another syntax to get at the files in twig?

I guess I need this... '%kerner.root_dir%/path/to/the/files'

Comment: Could you list folders under "web/bundles"?

Comment: yes @DonCallisto  ... they are framework and sensiodistribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every thing that you install through composer json goes to vendor folder (outside web folder)

you should check under web/bundles/ folder if you are in a linux or osx OS, if you are under windows, i don't think you'll have symlinks (so probably it's a hard copy each time you make a composer update). anyway. i think you should never use %kernel.root_dir% on twig. 
in my case one of the bundles i'm using are symlinked under web/bundles to the real folder. as example guzzle :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odin odin   88 ago  9 13:47 guzzle -> ../../vendor/eightpoints/guzzle-bundle/EightPoints/Bundle/GuzzleBundle/Resources/public/
```

so probably the path you should be using is:

```
bundles/twbs/bootstrap/css/boostrap.css
bundles/twbs/bootstrap/css/boostrap-theme.css
bundles/yourbundle/css/custom.css
```

and instead of using the public folder of app, at least in the documentation recomends adding css, js, and img folder inside web (if you are using them in more than one bundle)

Comment: Thanks for the help Erwin, I changed twig as per your suggestion and used the following {% stylesheets 
            'bundles/twbs/bootstrap/css/boostrap.css' 
            'bundles/twbs/bootstrap/css/boostrap-theme.css'
            'bundles/AppBundle/css/custom.css'
            filter='cssrewrite' %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            {% endstylesheets %} This is how it is shown in the documentation for the assetic manager, however I'm still getting the runtime exception error ~file not found.

Comment: did it work? because based on your answer to @DonCallisto, you don't have twbs symlink folder insider your web/bundles/. btw did you run 

    php app/console assets:install --symlink

Comment: Im hunting around now for the folders @Erwin It seems that even though sublime shows them as a symlink folder I can traverse the expected filestructure in the terminal. I in fact did not use the --symlink modifier. Will try that now.

Comment: Ok so I ran php app/console assets:install --symlink. I made sure my twig file used the above mentioned syntax. I ran php/app console assetic:dump and I stil get RuntimeException the source file "/var/www/projectname/app/../web/twbs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" does not exist.

Comment: it looks like it is not using "bundles" folder (it looks for web/twbs/ instead of web/bundles/twbs/). i haven't used twbs, but i'll create a testing project and use that, to check the correct location of the files, or if they are being linked or not. which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I did leave out the word budles in the exception message, for that I'm sorry..the path it is trying to find is... /var/www/projectname/app/../web/bundles/twbs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: found your problem, twbs symlink is not added on your web/bundles folder... i think you should add it manually. what i did was getting inside web/bundles folder and add the symlink : "ln -s ../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist bootstrap"  then change the route on your twig file from "bundles/twbs/bootstrap"to "bundles/bootstrap" and you should be ok.

Comment: OK ive run your command on the web/bundles folder for both bootstrap and for jquery later in the twig template. Now I see "bootstrap" folder inside web/bundles. I've changed the %stylesheets% path to look like this. 'bundles/bootstrap/css/boostrap.css' and I'm still getting the same error. Can't find the path, and it is still running the same path we discussed earlier.

Comment: do you have the twbs/bootstrap/dist/ inside the project/vendor folder... if not, then composer update did not downloaded the files and you should run composer -vvv update on the root project folder and check if it's downloading the files needed (the -vvv shows a lot of info)

Comment: I ran the command, and DEEP in a list of packages I see..both the twbs and components vendors. It says reading from /root/.composer on both. Later after this long list it says nothing to install or update.

Comment: did you have any luck?, i didn't used twbs bundle for bootstrap, instead i downloaded directly from getbootstrap.com and put them into web/css web/fonts and web/js because i'm using bootstrap on backend and frontend, so it didn't had much use to have them in a bundle folder, i saw that there are other bundles that have bootstrap on it, and they need to be loaded on AppKernel.php, so they auto create the symlink under web/bundles folder, but the twbs vendor you're using, doesn't have this option.

Comment: Erwin, thanks so much for your help. In more searching around the intertubes I found that using composer to get the bootstrap and jquery bundles is not the way to go anyway. I ended up using your last suggestion... just getting the files myself and loading them into the web/ directories. Though I din't actually "solve" my problem as originally stated, I did learn a whole lot through my interaction with you!

Comment: glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do a `php app/console assetic:dump` in the terminal to dump the required assets into your web folder where they'll be publicly accessible to reference in your code.

Comment: Thanks for interest BT643, however on running assetic:dump i get the error..Runtime Exception ...path/to/file doesn't exist.